# How to change number of workers and threads in running process for gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn

I want to test performance of WEB service that running inside AWS ECS service depending on number of `gunicorn` workers.

Entrypoint of the container is:

```bash
WORKERS=15
THREADS=15

gunicorn \
  --reload \
  --workers "${WORKERS}" \
  --threads "${THREADS}" \
  --max-requests 10000 \
  --max-requests-jitter 200 \
  --timeout 60 \
  --access-logfile - \
  --error-logfile - \
  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
  config.wsgi:application
```

#### The problem:

If I want to change number of workers / threads I have to stop `gunicorn` → update ECS Task definition (set new number of `WORKERS` and `THREADS`) → restart ECS container. It takes too much time if I want to test tens of configurations.

#### Possible workaround:

It is possible to set mock endless `entrypoint` like `watch -n 1000 "ls -l"` and login to ECS container with `bash` and run `gunicorn` with desired parameters manually. But it is little bit inconvenient and suppose to create test specific environment. So, I want to avoid this method.

#### The question:

Is it possible to change number of workers and threads of already running `gunicorn` instance? To be able test different configurations without rerunning container and stopping its entrypoint process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [config file](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#config) and reload the config by sending `HUP` signal to the `gunicorn` master process.
See: [reload configuration](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html?highlight=reload#reload-the-configuration)

Here is a simple example:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn",  "app:app"]
```

```bash
# tree ./
.
├── app.py
├── Dockerfile
├── gunicorn.conf.py
└── requirements.txt

# cat gunicorn.conf.py
workers = 2
threads = 2
loglevel = 'debug'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
pidfile = '/var/run/app.pid'

# reload the configuration by
kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/app.pid)
```

Comment: It makes sense. Better than nothing. But I still want to avoid editing files inside a container. Store number of workers inside application or environment variable will be perfect. And could you add in your answer that `HUP` signal may be sent by `kill -HUP "$(ps hf -opid -C gunicorn | awk '{ print $1; exit }')"` command?

Comment: @rzlvmp you could set `pidfile` in the config, e.g., `pidfile = /var/run/app.pid`. So that, you coud simplify the reload command to `kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/app.pid)`